# Python: Find largest number from column after specific word in a text file

Tags: python, python-3.6

I'm new to python so there maybe rookie mistakes in my code. I have a large text which resembles the text below.

data.txt

```
Apple

12 83 84 85 96 83 84
19 93 84 21 83 94 72
37 84 95 10 94 65 35
63 83 85 18 83 85 83

Banana

12 28 39 26 88 90 38  
25 37 88 99 80 74 26 
17 25 36 46 54 63 79
89 96 14 26 31 43 56
```

I need my code to find the word Banana (or a specific word) and find the largest number from the last column and print it. My plan is to make a loop that checks if the word Banana is on the line and keep doing in until the word is found. Next I save all the numbers from the last column to a variable and use a command to find the largest number and print it. Here's my code so far

```
file = open("/home/user/data.txt", 'r')
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()

for line in lines:
    if "Banana" in line:
        for line in lines:
             parts = line.split()
    if len(parts) > 1:
        column2 = parts[6]
        print(max(column2))
    else:
        pass
```

Here is what my code gives

```
8
7
5
8
6
9
6
```

For some reason the code prints the biggest number from every line (even though I want it to ignore everything expect the numbers under word Banana) and thinks that numbers are one digit numbers. After the first loop when the word Banana is found, the code goes to beginning of the text file and then finds the largest number from every single line. How can i make my code to check only the numbers after the specific word? Can someone tell me what is wrong with my code? I'm using python 3.6.5-3 on Linux. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.groupby` to separate the words from the digits, which can be used to create a dictionary with the maximum value from the last column:

```
import itertools
import re
with open('data.txt') as f:
  new_data = list(filter(None, [i.strip('\n') for i in f]))
  new_groups = [list(b) for _, b in itertools.groupby(new_data, key=lambda x:x.isalpha())]
  d = {new_groups[i][0]:list(map(lambda x:list(map(int, x.split())), new_groups[i+1])) for i in range(0, len(new_groups), 2)}
  maxs = {a:max([i[-1] for i in b]) for a, b in d.items()}
  print(maxs['Banana'])
```

Output:

```
79
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the last number from each line:

```
data = "12 83 84 85 96 83 84"

print [ int(x) for x in data.split() ].pop()
```

a full example:

```
input = """
Apple

12 83 84 85 96 83 84
19 93 84 21 83 94 72
37 84 95 10 94 65 35
63 83 85 18 83 85 83

Banana

12 28 39 26 88 90 38
25 37 88 99 80 74 26
17 25 36 46 54 63 79
89 96 14 26 31 43 56
"""
foundIt = False
vals = []
for line in input.split("\n"):

    if "" == line:
        continue

    if "Banana" == line:
        foundIt = True
        continue;

    if foundIt:
        print line
        try:
            vals.append( [ int(x) for x in line.split() ].pop())

        except:
            break;


print vals
print max(vals)
```

output:

```
12 28 39 26 88 90 38  
25 37 88 99 80 74 26 
17 25 36 46 54 63 79
89 96 14 26 31 43 56
[38, 26, 79, 56]
79
```

Answer (score 0):

Find lines after `"Banana"`, get the last numbers of those lines using `.split()[-1]` and find the maximum of them:

```
check = False
numbers = []
with open('file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        if check and line:
            numbers.append(int(line.split()[-1]))
        if line.strip() == 'Banana':
            check = True

print(max(numbers))
# 79
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open("a.txt", 'r')
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()
banana = False
maximum = 0
for line in lines:
    if "Banana" in line:
        banana = True
    if banana:
        try:
            number = int(line.split()[6])
            if number > maximum:
                maximum = number
            #print(number)
        except(IndexError):
            pass
print (maximum)
```

I used a variable that sets to true once it sees 'banana'. I also used try catch to avoid the line which is blank. And then I found the maximum number

Comment: My text file formatting changed and now I have text over every column and I get an error "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:" because I have a string mixed with integers. So now I need the code to find the word "Banana" and then ignore the text line of text and then find the largest number. I tried to make two for loops. The first one finds the word banana and the second one checks if there are words on next and then does everything as in your code starting from try: number=int(line.split()[6]). How should I write the second loop?